# Relationship between Opportunity and Contract

Tags: custom-field, relationships

How to make a relationship between contract and Opportunity ??

Comment: Do you want to have multiple contracts per opportunity or multiple opportunities per contract?

Comment: For Multiple opportunities per contract .

Answer (score 1):

Normally, an Opportunity that goes to closed-won results in a contract between your company and the customer.

Hence, a simple solution is to add a lookup field from Contract to Opportunity.  This would support a use case wherein one Opportunity can yield 0+ Contracts. A related list under Opportunity would show such Contract(s).

Answer (score 1):

Contracts have an approval and activate mechanism that allows for greater controls by the organization as to what is an actual sale. It is up to the Sales rep to determine a closed sale with respect to the stage involved as opposed to a manager signing off on the contract after a document has been signed. Standard contracts within Salesforce.com do not relate to any specific opportunity. Data as to what has been sold to a client with respect to products, pricing, schedules and such is not housed on the contract entity I think a linear one-to-one relationship should be created between opportunities and contracts that pulls all of the exisiting information in a given opportunity (i.e. products, notes, history, pricing) and submits it as a draft contract to the manager. The opportunity is then locked for editing or deleting by the Sales rep pending activation by the manager. Once validation of a signature from the client is obtained the manager can activate the contract, if it is not obatined they can open it back up and the Sales rep can work the opportunity until siganture is obtained. After activation the contract is the single source of truth for data within the system and can be counted on as accurate when reporting is done. Further, versioning should exist if the contract needs to be edited after activation in the case of cancelation, changed in contract length or size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a contract lookup on Opportunity, you just need to make field level security || Accessibility to that field for your user as visible.